# Shell :Select lowercase words from a file,sort them and copy to another file

Tags: regex, shell, unix

I want to make a shell script which gets two parameters from command line,the first should be an existing file,another one the new file which will contents the result.From the first file,i want to select the lowercase words and then sort them and copy the result in second file. The grep command is obviously not good,how should i change it to get the result?

```
#!/bin/bash
file1=$1
file2=$2
if [ ! -f $file1]
then
    echo "this file doesn't exist or is not a file
    break
else
    grep '/[a-z]*/' $file1 | sort > $file2
```

Comment: Fixing the code block formatting underlined a missing closing quote. You should also have a space before the closing bracket in the `if`'s condition. The `break` has no meaning in a `if/then/else/fi` block, and you're missing the `fi`. The `grep` is almost fine, but `/.../` is a JavaScript construct : you will want to remove the slashes. You might want to check [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), a website in which you can paste your code and should point out such mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the grep command like this:

```
grep -o '\<[[:lower:]][[:lower:]]*\>' "$file1" | sort -u > "$file2"
```

The -o is an output control switch that forces grep to return each match in a newline.

`\<` is a left word boundary and `\>` a right word boundary. *(this way the word `Site` doesn't return `ite`)*
`[[:lower:]][[:lower:]]*` ensures there's at least one lower case letter.
*(The use of `[[:lower:]]` instead of the range `[a-z]` is preferable because with some locales, letters may be alphabetically ordered despite of the character case: `aBbCcDd...YyZz`)*

Notice: I added the -u switch to the sort command to remove duplicate entries, if you don't want this behaviour, remove it.

Comment: Both `$file1` and `$file2` should be inside double-quotes here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a hurry so I won't rewrite what I pointed out in a comment, but here is your code with all these problems fixed :

```
#!/bin/bash
file1=$1
file2=$2
if [ ! -f $file1 ]
then
    echo "this file doesn't exist or is not a file"
else
    grep '[a-z]*' $file1 | sort > $file2
fi
```

ShellCheck gives one more tip which you should definitely apply, I'll let you check it out.

It would also be a good practice to exit with a non-zero code when the script can't execute its task, that is in your case when the file isn't found.

Comment: It was also needed `grep -wo` to select only the characters. i find it out right now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Using awk and `sort`, First the test file:

```
$ cat file
This is a test.
This is another one.
```

Code:

```
$ awk -v RS="[ .\n]+" '/^[[:lower:]]+$/' file | sort
a
another
is
is
one
test
```

I'm using space, newline and period as record separator to separate each word as its own record and print words that consists of only lower case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell code could use some fixing up.

```
#!/bin/bash
file1=$1
file2=$2
if [ ! -f "$file1" ] # need space before ]; quote expansions
  # send error messages to stderr instead of stdout 
  # include program and file name in message
  printf >&2 '%s: file "%s" does not exist or is not a file\n' "$0" "$file1"
  # exit with nonzero code when something goes wrong
  exit 1
fi

# -w to get only whole words
# -o to print out each match on a separate line
grep -wo '[a-z][a-z]*' "$file1" | sort > "$file2"
```

As written that will include multiple copies of the same word if it occurs multiple times in the file; change to `sort -u` if you don't want that.